# Fetching data from an API with JSON and storing two objects in a single row of an Array Adapter

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter

I've got this code with fetches the "rate" data from an API, along with "rate", I need to get the "name". If I get "name" it often binds it below the "rate".

I need it to join on the same row of the List View, so it is like [Rate Name].

I need to get two objects of a JSON Array and bind it to the array adapter so I can display two objects in the same row of a List View so it is more user friendly.

The code below is of the AsyncTask, the code works fine but I need to add one more object and make sure it is displayed as one rate - one name and then iterating through the loop and adding more as needed in the same order.

```
public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // the url of the web service to call
    String yourServiceUrl = "eg: URL";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    String filename = "bitData";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {
            // create new instance of the httpConnect class
            httpConnect jParser = new httpConnect();

            // get json string from service url
            String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourServiceUrl);

            // parse returned json string into json array
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

            // loop through json array and add each currency to item in arrayList
            //Custom Loop Initialise
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                JSONObject json_message = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
             // The second JSONObject which needs to be added 
                JSONObject json_name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                if (json_message != null) {
                    //add each currency to ArrayList as an item
                    items.add(json_message.getString("rate"));


                    String bitData = json_message.getString("rate");


                    String writeData = bitData + ',' +'\n';

                    FileOutputStream outputStream;
                    File file = getFileStreamPath(filename);


                    // first check if file exists, if not create it
                    if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
                        try {
                            outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE);
                            outputStream.write(writeData.getBytes());
                            outputStream.write("\r\n".getBytes());
                            outputStream.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    // if file already exists then append bit data to it
                    else if (file.exists()) {
                        try {
                            outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
                            outputStream.write(writeData.getBytes());
                            outputStream.write("\r\n".getBytes());
                            outputStream.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;


    }

    // below method will run when service HTTP request is complete, will then bind text in arrayList to ListView
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rateView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> rateArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BitRates.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);
        list.setAdapter(rateArrayAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly create a class with two objects for rate and name.  And then Create  a custom ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2):

Just Create Custom Class Messsage:

```
public class Item{
   private String name;
   private String rate;

   public void Message(String n, String r){
      this.name=n;
      this.rate=r;
 }
// create here getter and setter
}
```

Now in your background, you have to add name and rate in Message class

```
 Public class MainAcitity extends Activity{    
   public static List<Item> items= new ArrayList<>();// define in inside the class
```

// this has to be down on background

```
Item i=new Item(json_message.getString("name"),json_message.getString("rate"));
items.add(i);
```

Now pass this listmessge onPostExecute :

```
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rateView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> rateArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BitRates.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);
    list.setAdapter(rateArrayAdapter);
```

Is that any helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, it definitely helps to simplify the problem. But where exactly do you need me to declare the List<Item>, because inner classes cannot have static declaration.

Comment: you have to put just below the Activity scope, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link.You will get my point.
https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/